# How to add an object that is attached to an ObjectContext, to an EntityCollection that is not associated with a source object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I am trying to sort a child-collection with the Entity Framework. This is my code:

```
        var query = db.Category
            .Where(p => p.parrent_id == null)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.prefix)
            .Select(o => new 
            {
                Category = o,
                SubCategories = o.Category1.OrderBy(h => h.prefix)
            });

        IEnumerable<Category> cats = query.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new Category
            {
                category_id = x.Category.category_id,
                parrent_id = x.Category.parrent_id,
                category_name = x.Category.category_name,
                prefix = x.Category.prefix,
                Category1 = x.SubCategories.ToEntityCollection()
            });
```

the ToEntityCollection method looks like this:

```
        public static EntityCollection<T> ToEntityCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class
    {
        var es = new EntityCollection<T>();
        foreach (T e in source)
        {
            es.Add(e);
        }
        return es;
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The object could not be added to the EntityCollection or EntityReference. An object that is attached to an ObjectContext cannot be added to an EntityCollection or EntityReference that is not associated with a source object.
```

on

```
es.Add(e);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote the exact same extension method for myself and came across the same problem.  I am using the same context to load the entities, but I still receive the error.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

this has been asked before: [Error Using ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382161/error-using-ado-net-entity-framework#comment2359843_2382161)

See here for why Attach rather than Add should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Answer (score -2):

You can't attach entities to a different context when they are attached to a different one. You need to detach it from the previous one if you relay want to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx

Comment: Where in the code should i detach it? I tried query.ToList.Foreach(q => db.Detach(q)); And i get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: The object cannot be detached because it is not attached to the ObjectStateManager.